# SharePoint color picker modal dialogue box not auto adjusting

Tags: modal-dialog

**Background:**
- I have a custom SharePoint masterpage with custom CSS. 
- I also placed a custom `div` into the `masterpage.html`

**Problem:**
When I use the color picker to change some font color and select "more colors…", the modal dialogue box that comes up is too small and has scroll bars.

I would like for it to auto adjust.

How do I fix this?
I tried using F12 to figure out what CSS element may be affecting it, but I am unable to figure it out.

**Note:** I tried removing the custom `div` but the problem persists.

If I get two more reputation points I can upload a picture so you can visually see what I am talking about. A picture is worth a thousand words:/

Or you can go [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249109/color-picker-dialogue-box-not-sizing-correctly) to see the pic.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I was able to figure it out:

I update the following custom css with `300px !Important`:

```
#contentBox
{
margin-right:20px;
margin-left:20px;
min-width:300px !Important;
}
```

And I added the below custom css:

```
.more-colors-picker
{
margin: 0px;
}
```

For a complete history and explanation with pictures go [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/249109/color-picker-dialogue-box-not-sizing-correctly)